# Why this query fails with ORA-1722 (Invalid number)

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query fails with ORA-1722 when executed within a package

```
sQ:='Select * 
       from baan.TTDSLS031010  
      where t$cuno = :cuno
        and trim(t$cpgs) = Trim(:cpgs) 
        and to_char(t$tdat,:dfmt) >= to_char(:stdt,:dfmt)
        and to_char(t$stdt,:dfmt) = to_char( (select max(t$stdt) 
                                                from baan.TTDSLS031010 
                                               where t$cuno = :cuno 
                                                 and trim(t$cpgs) = trim(:cpgs))
                                           ,:dfmt )';      
 execute immediate sq 
    into r31 
   using cuno,cpgs,dfmt,stdt,dfmt,dfmt,cuno,cpgs,dfmt;
```

but executed as anonymous block is successful.

```
set serveroutput on

Declare sq varchar2(3000);
  R31  BAAN.TTDSLS031010%rowtype;
  cuno varchar2(6) := '000120';
  cpgs varchar2(6) := '1AB00';
  stdt date := '2014-09-22';
  dfmt varchar2(15) := 'YYYY-MM-DD';
Begin
  sQ:='Select * 
         from baan.TTDSLS031010  
        where t$cuno = :cuno
          and trim(t$cpgs) = Trim(:cpgs) 
          and to_char(t$tdat,:dfmt) >= to_char(:stdt,:dfmt)
          and to_char(t$stdt,:dfmt) = to_char( (select max(t$stdt)
                                                  from baan.TTDSLS031010
                                                 where t$cuno = :cuno 
                                                   and trim(t$cpgs) = trim(:cpgs))
                                              ,:dfmt)';      
   execute immediate sq 
      into r31 
     using cuno,cpgs,dfmt,stdt,dfmt,dfmt,cuno,cpgs,dfmt;

   dbms_output.put_line('R31.cuno='||r31.t$cuno);
end;
```

What could be wrong ?

Comment: My first guess is that the arguments are different, particularly `:cuno`.

Comment: You are overcomplicating things. There is no need for native dynamic SQL in the code you've provided. Make it static(will be easier to debug). PL/SQL will bind variables anyway.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov, The reason for dynamic sql is that the tables from which data is fetched can vary,The application(BaaN ERP) maintains a separate table for each so called 'Logical Company', Actual code do use a function to retrieve the physical table name, so Static sql is not an option. Thanks anyway for looking into it .